# Javascript Lookbehind with Global Search Overlapped

Tags: javascript, regex, global, lookbehind

There are several (sometimes tricky) solutions for lookbehind regexps in Javascript. But, which is the easiest way, if I need a **zero width!** look behind expression with global search, which may overlap. E.g. using `/(?<=[01])\d/g` we could do the following:

```js
let a = "--1--01001--1087---";
let result = a.replace(/(?<=[01])\d/g, "#");
// This should print "--1--0####--1##7---" if lookbehind would be supported
console.log(result);
```

Or another example: How can we create a `\b` like expression which works with letters only (`[a-zA-Z]`). (Lookforward is no question. Just JS does not support lookbehind).

Answer (score 1):

The *look-behind through reversal* approach seems the easiest here.
This approach is best with short numeric patterns like this one.

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var s = "--1--01001--1087---";
var rxp = /\d(?=[01])/g;

var result = revStr(revStr(s).replace(rxp, "#"));
document.write(result);
```

Logics:

- `\d(?=[01])` is a reversed regex for `(?<=[01])\d`
- We reverse the input string with `revStr(s)` function
- We reverse the replacement result again to obtain final outcome.

**NOTE**:

In case you need both variable-width look-behind *and* look-ahead in JavaScript, I can recommend reading [JavaScript Regex Lookbehind Redux](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind) article by Steven Levithan, where you can find a sample function showing how to implement that behavior using [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp). Here are the functions:

```
// Simulating infinite-length leading lookbehind in JavaScript. Uses XRegExp.
// Captures within lookbehind are not included in match results. Lazy
// repetition in lookbehind may lead to unexpected results.

(function (XRegExp) {

    function prepareLb(lb) {
        // Allow mode modifier before lookbehind
        var parts = /^((?:\(\?[\w$]+\))?)\(\?<([=!])([\s\S]*)\)$/.exec(lb);
        return {
            // $(?!\s) allows use of (?m) in lookbehind
            lb: XRegExp(parts ? parts[1] + "(?:" + parts[3] + ")$(?!\\s)" : lb),
            // Positive or negative lookbehind. Use positive if no lookbehind group
            type: parts ? parts[2] === "=" : !parts
        };
    }

    XRegExp.execLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var pos = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                return match;
            }
            pos = match.index + 1;
        }
        return null;
    };

    XRegExp.testLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        return !!XRegExp.execLb(str, lb, regex);
    };

    XRegExp.searchLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var match = XRegExp.execLb(str, lb, regex);
        return match ? match.index : -1;
    };

    XRegExp.matchAllLb = function (str, lb, regex) {
        var matches = [], pos = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                matches.push(match[0]);
                pos = match.index + (match[0].length || 1);
            } else {
                pos = match.index + 1;
            }
        }
        return matches;
    };

    XRegExp.replaceLb = function (str, lb, regex, replacement) {
        var output = "", pos = 0, lastEnd = 0, match, leftContext;
        lb = prepareLb(lb);
        while (match = XRegExp.exec(str, regex, pos)) {
            leftContext = str.slice(0, match.index);
            if (lb.type === lb.lb.test(leftContext)) {
                // Doesn't work correctly if lookahead in regex looks outside of the match
                output += str.slice(lastEnd, match.index) + XRegExp.replace(match[0], regex, replacement);
                lastEnd = match.index + match[0].length;
                if (!regex.global) {
                    break;
                }
                pos = match.index + (match[0].length || 1);
            } else {
                pos = match.index + 1;
            }
        }
        return output + str.slice(lastEnd);
    };

}(XRegExp));
```

Each of these functions takes three arguments: the string to search, the lookbehind pattern as a string (can use XRegExp syntax extensions), and the main regex. `XRegExp.replaceLb` takes a fourth argument for the replacement value, which can be a string or function.

Usage examples follow:

```
XRegExp.execLb("Fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<=fluffy\\W+)", XRegExp("(?i)(?<first>c)at"));
// -> ["cat", "c"]
// Result has named backref: result.first -> "c"

XRegExp.execLb("Fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat/i);
// -> null

XRegExp.testLb("Fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<=fluffy\\W+)", /cat/i);
// -> true

XRegExp.testLb("Fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat/i);
// -> false

XRegExp.searchLb("Catwoman's fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<=fluffy\\W+)", /cat/i);
// -> 18

XRegExp.searchLb("Catwoman's fluffy cat", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat/i);
// -> 0

XRegExp.matchAllLb("Catwoman's cats are fluffy cats", "(?i)(?<=fluffy\\W+)", /cat\w*/i);
// -> ["cats"]

XRegExp.matchAllLb("Catwoman's cats are fluffy cats", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat\w*/i);
// -> ["Catwoman", "cats"]

XRegExp.replaceLb("Catwoman's fluffy cat is a cat", "(?i)(?<=fluffy\\W+)", /cat/ig, "dog");
// -> "Catwoman's fluffy dog is a cat"

XRegExp.replaceLb("Catwoman's fluffy cat is a cat", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat/ig, "dog");
// -> "dogwoman's fluffy cat is a dog"

XRegExp.replaceLb("Catwoman's fluffy cat is a cat", "(?i)(?<!fluffy\\W+)", /cat/ig, function ($0) {
    var first = $0.charAt(0);
    return first === first.toUpperCase() ? "Dog" : "dog";
});
// -> "Dogwoman's fluffy cat is a dog"
```

Comment: Unless you need a variable-width look-behind with variable-width look-ahead, this reversal approach seems to work best for overlapping matches. And the amount of code is not that big. Also, regex patterns are not that hard to reverse.

Comment: I find this said, but it looks, that there is no other choice. Actually, sometimes we also need both look-behind and look-ahead (not common: I think, I used it about 5 times during 16 years Perl, but still).

Comment: In case you need both variable-width look-behind and look-ahead in JavaScript, I can recommend reading [JavaScript Regex Lookbehind Redux](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind) article by Steven Levithan, where you can find a sample function showing how to implement that behavior using [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp).